Clearpath nav2 demos map not being published
I'm running the Clearpath nav2 demos and getting this error when running the nav2 launch file "StaticLayer: "map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist." .
Using tf2_tools I checked the TF tree and got No tf data received, so I'm assuming there is something wrong with the TF publishing, what is really confusing me is that up until yesterday everything worked correctly and I have made no changes.

Unfortunately this is not enough information to go off of. There are many possible things that could be causing this. Can you start by providing the terminal output from all terminals used? (simulation, rviz, localization, nav2) and confirm that you are pressing play on your simulation and that you have set the initial position. Are you able to drive the robot in Gazebo still? I ask to confirm that the simulation is fully functional and that it is only the localization that is failing.

@HilaryLuo Yes the simulation seems to be fully functional I set the initial position, rviz is able to load the map and I can drive the robot in gazebo. Gazebo doesn't display any errors, in rviz the only errors are related to the map frame not existing, here are the localization and nav2 outputs.

I will take a look at that output but wanted to quickly add, make sure that when you try and run the TF tree command, that you include the namespacing, for example: ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames --ros-args -r __ns:=/j100_0000 -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static

@HilaryLuo I managed to find the problem, I apparently made some changes to the robot.yaml file (and forgot) which led nothing being published on the /scan topic. Thank you for the help!

I managed to find the problem, in the robot.yaml file the lidars weren't configured properly leading to nothing being published on the /scan topic resulting in the error I mentioned.
